# Documentation with NDOC3

Tags: xml, documentation, ndoc

I am working on a project documentation using NDOC3.

The build fails when trying to document 3rd party DLLs (because I do not have the xml documentation for them).
How could I address this issue ?

Comment: Did you check the Xml Documentation file option at the build options for each project in the solution?? That was the solution in my case. Cheers Andreu

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of documenting without the 3rd party DLLs, as NDoc loads everything via reflection first, then inspects the XML file to match the types. So it needs all dependencies in order for the reflection loading to be successful.